# AWS Recognition to Compare Face using IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I have an issue with my logic trying to invoke the `AWS` Recognition Compare Faces api using `IOS Swift`.  There isn't any documentation for `Swift` yet (as of this posting), but believe I may have the request set up correctly, just not invoking it correctly to receive the response object and confirm the results.

Any advice?

```
let sourceImage = AWSRekognitionImage()
let sourceImageS3Object = AWSRekognitionS3Object()
sourceImageS3Object?.bucket = "face-badges"
sourceImageS3Object?.name = "me.jpg"
sourceImage?.s3Object = sourceImageS3Object

let targetImage = AWSRekognitionImage()
let targetImageS3Object = AWSRekognitionS3Object()
targetImageS3Object?.bucket = "face-badges"
targetImageS3Object?.name = "me2.jpg"
targetImage?.s3Object = targetImageS3Object

let request = AWSRekognitionCompareFacesRequest()
request?.similarityThreshold = 90
request?.sourceImage = sourceImage
request?.targetImage = targetImage

let key = "testCompareFaces"
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USEast1,
                                                        identityPoolId:"xxxxx")
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

AWSRekognition.register(with: configuration!, forKey: key)
AWSRekognition(forKey: key).compareFaces(AWSRekognitionCompareFacesRequest()).continueWith(block: {(_ task: AWSTask) -> Any in
    print("completed")

    return true;

}).waitUntilFinished()
```

Comment: This documentation is 3 month old - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-rekognition-celebrity-detection-ios/tree/master/AWSRekognitionStarterApp

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amazon-rekognition-detects-celebrities-in-ios-app/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use AWS Rekognition to Compare Face in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483447/how-to-use-aws-rekognition-to-compare-face-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 4):

The following sample test in the SDK demonstrated how to compare two faces in ObjC.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSRekognitionUnitTests/AWSGeneralRekognitionTests.m#L60

Corresponding snippet in Swift would look something like :

```
let key = "testCompareFaces"
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionUSEast2, credentialsProvider: nil)
AWSRekognition.register(with: configuration, forKey: key)
AWSRekognition(for: key).compareFaces(AWSRekognitionCompareFacesRequest()).continue(withBlock: {(_ task: AWSTask) -> Any in
    print("completed")
```

Hope that helps!